# Excel continues time function graph

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I would like to make a plot in excel. graph represent stock amount and months. but I would like to do it continuous time. Each mounth it starts from 30 it decrease in time to 10 until next month and stock goes 30 again each month with 20 piece increase. I couldn't post the graph here. Thanks for your all help.

"http://i.hizliresim.com/G5QE26.jpg"   this is the link that i want to do.

Comment: Thanks good idea. I editted the post .

Comment: I see -- by "stock" you mean inventory and you are using an inventory model which assumes constant demand and has a safety stock of 10 units

Comment: Exactly that is what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you started.

You could use a scatterplot with straight lines connecting the data points:

[image]

There are numerous ways to tweak the appearance, though I don't know of any easy way to get the numbers to appear as dates.

Comment: Thanks for that . It helped me also.